# Connecting a Facebook App with an existing facebook page

Tags: facebook

I am registered as a developer on Facebook with my personal account which runs a few pages. I however have a client with there own Facebook fan page, I have added myself on as an admin to this page. But being a business page you cant create apps to add like buttons to websites.

How can I link an app on my account to this Facebook fan page?

Comment: What do you mean by “linking” in this context?

Comment: I just need to add a like button to a website for the page, but being a business account I cant find a way of doing it.

Comment: You don’t _have_ to use an app id for the like button. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/

Comment: How is this linked back to the Facebook fan page? It would work fine if i made a fan page from my personal account, but this is a fan page of a business account

Comment: By giving the address of the FB fanpage in the according parameter …?

Comment: The only URL parameter is the page to be liked IE the websites URL. Left blank this defaults to the page the like button is placed.

Comment: Not what do you want the user clicking on the like button to like – your external web page, or the FB fanpage?

Comment: I placed the code generated but get this error
Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. all.js:56
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().